# How to sort two tables basics on first

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I am looking for solution where I can sort the second table the same as the first table. For example I want to sort names (first table) and then in second table tr change position same as like in first table.

As example I will give you link to my fiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $tableLeft = $('.table-left'),
    $tableRight = $('.table-right'),
    $sortButton = $('.sort');

  $sortButton.on('click', function() {
    // I don't know what i have to do...
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-table {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-table>div:first-child {
  width: 80px;
}

.table-left {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.table-left>table td,
.table-left>table th {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

table td {
  height: 20px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead {
  height: 50px;
}

.sort {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-table">
  <div class="table-left">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2" class="sort"><b>Name</b></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Thomas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mathew</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Andreas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Kowalski</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="table-right">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Testing new</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Testing old</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Testing nothing</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Version</th>
          <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>0.7</td>
          <td>2017</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>0.5</td>
          <td>2015</td>
          <td>No</td>
          <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>0.8</td>
          <td>2018</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>0.6</td>
          <td>2016</td>
          <td>No</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nienormalny/ng34Lsa9/1/)

I think something should be done with indexing, but I'm not sure. It would be nice to find some help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Datatables jQuery Plugin with the simplest configuration in case you want the short solution.

See: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: I am looking for solution without Plugin